# Действия PHP. laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Объясните начинающему. 
У меня есть контроллер, но есть логика, действие. Куда ее помещать? в контроллер? или на это есть отдельные папки\файлы?

Comment: Какая именно логика и какие именно действия?

Comment: Самое главное, разместить логику в своей голове ;)

Comment: Это верно ! Скажи а дорого стоят учителя личные ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Логику общую для запросов - в middleware.
- Общую для нескольких сущностей - в сервисы.
- Логику отображения - в вид.
- Преобразования данных - в модель.
- Двухсторонний обмен между моделью и видом - в контролер.